# lando start spits out "ERROR: for proxy Cannot start service proxy: network"

Tags: lando

```
lando start


There is an update available!!!
Install it to get the latest and greatest


Updating helps us provide the best support
https://github.com/lando/lando/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.39


Creating network "landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_edge" with driver "bridge"
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... 
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... error

ERROR: for landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Creating network "landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_edge" with driver "bridge"
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... 
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... error

ERROR: for landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Creating network "landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_edge" with driver "bridge"
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... 
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... error

ERROR: for landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Creating network "landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_edge" with driver "bridge"
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... 
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... error

ERROR: for landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Creating network "landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_edge" with driver "bridge"
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... 
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... error

ERROR: for landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: network 1d993c7e5a1c13a1c11dc6604eada65a5fce906e466f506f9b9ca6ca33580cc4 not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
error:  Error: Error
    at /snapshot/cli/lib/promise.js:0:0
    at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
From previous event:
    at rec (/snapshot/cli/lib/promise.js:0:0)
    at /snapshot/cli/lib/promise.js:0:0
    at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5)
From previous event:
    at /snapshot/cli/lib/promise.js:0:0
    at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the proxy container.

```
docker container rm CONTAINER-NAME
```

in your case:

```
docker container rm landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1
```

Comment: This soluiton worked!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to update `lando` to the latest version

https://github.com/lando/lando/releases/

Comment: which version where you using? And what version do you use now?

Comment: @FLY honestly I have no idea, but I would guesstimate I was on ~v3.0.0beta24 and moved to v3.0.0beta39 ???

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan I got this same error on beta40. Will try to downgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: `beta40` is still pre-release so, it's sketch